# JetBrains MPS editor with polymorphic list?

Tags: dsl, mps

I'm working with MPS for the first time, and hitting some interesting problems. One has stumped me.

I'm trying to create a simple DSL for music notation. I have a concept called TemporalUnit (something that occupies time), with sub-concepts of Note and Rest.

I'd like my Measure editor to allow a mixture of Notes and Rests. I declared it as having a list of TemporalUnits, but that seems to treat TemporalUnit as a concrete class, and Note and Rest are ignored. Is there a way I can have the editor allow a "heterogeneous" mix of subtypes of a common ancestor concept?

Comment: This should work, your problem must be somewhere else. Can you post more details, screenshots, etc.?

Comment: I figured it out (lucky guess, actually). Added 'abstract' keyword to the declaration of my TemporalUnits concept, which prevented the behavior of automatically creating TemporalUnit lines when editing a model.

Comment: In any case if MPS creates a TemporalUnit you should be able to substitute it with a Note or a Rest by pressing Ctrl+Space.